# If two vectors $A=ai-j-4k$ and $B=2i-bj+3k$ and $3A=2B$, what are the values of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: vectors

I have tried to solve it by first calculating $3A$ and $2B$. As these two vectors are equal their magnitudes should be equal too which gives me the equation

$ 9a^2+153=4b^2+52 
\implies9a^2-4b^2=-101 .......(1)$

the answer in the book is given as $a=4/3$ and $b=3/2$. I think these two values should satisfy equation $(1)$. But it doesn't.
Can anyone verify if I am doing the math in the wrong way or the answers are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two vectors are equal if and only if each of their components is equal.

The condition $3A=2B$ is saying $$3a\vec i-3\vec j -12\vec k = 4\vec i-2b\vec j+6\vec k.$$ See that the $\vec k$-component is not equal. A contradiction. Thus, there is no such $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The most likely explanation is an error in the question. Perhaps it should have read A = ai - j + 2k.

Comment: @Korn Kruaykitanon Hmm, that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

$$3 \times{\vec{A}}= 2\times{\vec{B}}$$
$$3(a\hat{i}-\hat{j}-4\hat{k})= 2(2\hat{i}-b\hat{j}+3\hat{k})$$
$$3a\hat{i}-3\hat{j}-12\hat{k}=4\hat{j}-2b\hat{j}+6\hat{k}$$
Equating the coefficients of î we get, $$3a=4;$$ which gives us $$ a = \frac43$$
and equating the coefficients of ĵ we get, $$-3=-2b$$ and that gives us $$b = \frac32$$